# Hive: Subtracting 1 year from current date

Tags: date, hadoop, hive, unix-timestamp, subtraction

I'm trying to find the best way to subtract 1 year and also one month from the current date in a Hive query. Using the following, I don't believe it will take into account leap years or if the fact that months have different amounts of days so eventually the code will break. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
set my_date = from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()-365*60*60*24, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
set my_date = from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()-30*60*60*24, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Thank!

-Rebecca

Answer (score -1):

If you have date format like yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss in Hive, it is easy to implement using following functions

concat((year(date_field)-1),'-', (month(date_field)-1), '-', day(date_field))

Use IF and CASE functions to implement your logic to find whether it is a leap year or not(by dividing year by 4)